# How can I programmatically duplicate a Tkinter font, replacing all the lowercase glyphs with uppercase glyphs?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I want to be able to show text in a Tkinter/ttk Text widget in all uppercase **without losing the original case info or having to manage/store it.** The easiest way I can think of is by reconfiguring a Text tag with an all-uppercase font version of the original font.  My Python app is cross-platform, running on Windows and OS X.  I prefer fixed-width fonts.

I would prefer a programmatic means to generate such an all-caps font on the fly based on some (standard) input font. What's the best way to do this?

Effectively, I want to be able to click a button to toggle certain selected text strings between the original case and all uppercase.  The Text widget holds all the data. There is no other container for the data.  A simple upper() call will not suffice for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Although not ideal, a potential workaround would be to find a pair of matching fixed-width fonts, one with mixed case and another essentially the same but with only uppercase letters.

Comment: use upper function maybe...

Comment: `upper()` doesn't change the string in place, so you can pass it when you assign the text, without changing the original string

Comment: you can get selected text from Text and use `upper()` to convert and put this text back to Text - but if you need original case then you have to keep it in some extra variable. You can't have original and converted text without using extra variable.

Comment: You can _probably_ clone a regular font and then have its lowercase letters overwritten as their uppercase counterparts with `fonttools` library.

Comment: you can't alter the fonts used by tkinter.

Comment: It *may* be possible to do this using a `ttk` `Style` where you can change the font associated with the Text widget? Citation needed.

Comment: @(Abhijeetk431, PRMoureu, furas) - upper() doesn't help me, because I don't want to have to manage a copy of the original text as entered.

Comment: @Nae - Thanks. I took a quick look, and that may be helpful.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley - True, but there are some platform-specific hacks which will allow me to temporarily (or permanently) install fonts for app use. I found the hack for Windows. I have to either find or generate one for OSX.

Comment: @EthanField - Changing the Text widget's font doesn't help, because I only want to deal with some substrings in the Text widget. That's why I am looking at using tags, to address certain substrings.  I'd like to config the tags with different fonts.

Comment: @Gary02127 I don't see any way of doing this without storing two versions of the contents of the `Text` or completely rewriting tkinter.

Comment: @EthanField - You're right that I need two copies of something, but I prefer to have two copies of the font and switch between the two fonts. Ideally I would generate a caps-only version of the basic fonts I use and it would all be invisible to the user.

Comment: @BryanOakley - Bryan, I saw online that you had written a Tk script to serialize a Text widget. Is there a Python version of that?  It could prove helpful in a related matter.

Comment: @Gary02127: no, I haven't created a python version.